# NET Platform Identify

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Do we have the ability to identify the NET platform even before we open and run the project?

I tried to open the project but got the error "Error while trying to load the project '/Volumes/xxx/xxx': File not found: /Volumes/xxx/xxx"

I am using the Mac OS Catalina. Googling up said that the project supported only windows not Mac. Please advise me.  Thank you

Comment: What's the *real* question? What project are you talking about? If you can google for it, it means it's a public project, maybe on GitHub? Given you can only use .NET Core or Mono on Mac, any project that *doesn't target one of those won't open

Comment: BTW the error doesn't suggest a platform incompatibility, it complains about bad paths. What does the *full* error say? I use Visual Studio solutions with multiple projects on Mac and Windows all the time and never encountered path problems. Unsupported project types won't even load

Comment: As for checking a project's target, open the `csproj` file. The .NET Core csproj format is minimal and the target runtime will appear at the top. If you see a long jumble of XML referencing specific types, it's the old format used for .NET Old projectss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows you can look for the solution file `.sln` (in the project folder) and open it with Notepad (it's a text doc) to find out the version of Visual Studio and .NET Framework used.

Comment: The solution file contains no information about the projects, must their paths

Comment: Ah. I see I'm looking at a website's sln file, not a project-only. In a project sln file, these are available, which might be useful (??): `VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1` and `MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1`. (Old projects. Maybe newer projects are very different.)